# jQuery Mobile List Filter Behave Like Auto-complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The jQuery Mobile listview and search filter works and looks great. However, I would like to change the behavior to behave more like an auto-complete control i.e. the list items don't appear until a search filter is entered.

I have seen other people using the jQuery UI auto-complete but it seems like overkill to have to include this library and extra work to style the results.

Can this be done with jQuery Mobile 1.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try something like this

- http://jsfiddle.net/ULXbb/3/
- http://jsfiddle.net/ULXbb/5/ (Button click)

JS

```
$("input[data-type='search']").keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $("ul:jqmData(role='listview')").children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden');
    }
});

$('a.ui-input-clear').click(function() {
    $("input[data-type='search']").val('');
    $("input[data-type='search']").trigger('keyup');
});
```

HTML (Need to add the class attribute to each `<li>` element `class="ui-screen-hidden"`)

```
<div data-role="page" id="filterMe">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Chrysler</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Dodge</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Ford</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">GMC</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Hyundai</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Infiniti</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Jeep</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Kia</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Lexus</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Mini</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Porsche</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Subaru</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Volkswagon</a></li>
            <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">Volvo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works great but we also need to handle the clear text button being pressed. I have updated my question with the code to do so. Perhaps someone with edit privileges could merge the two.

Comment: I have also added the button click functionality

Comment: This no longer works in JQM 1.1.0. I have reported the issue and they are now looking into it https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4539

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/ULXbb/48/

I have enabled its selection functionality. Now you can select items from the list. which is then written over to the input field and the list is made hidden.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this solution doesn't work any longer with JQuerymobile 1.1.0 and Jquery 1.7.2.

The entries from the list don't appear unless you press delete on your keyboard neither do they disappear when clearing the filter box…

edit: I found a great solution to make auto-complete work on this site: http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/27/jQuery-Mobile-Autocomplete-now-available

Comment: To get this to work in jQuery Mobile 1.0.0 I had to change jQuery.mobile-1.1.0.js. I removed the `if` statement on line 5818 and replaced it with `listItems = list.children();`